# C# net versions 4.8 HttpClient: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient

I want to send a simple request to "https://www.mexc.co/".

1.net versions  4.8

2.This website opens easily with a browser

3.There isn't any ssl validation error or warnings

**result: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.**

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;// | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

string url = "https://www.mexc.co/";
var res = httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result;===>return an error:
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you get a Wireshark trace on the Server Hello and Client Hello? I would imagine the server also supports TLS1.2, so it may just be a cipher mismatch. Side notes: do ot change `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol`, just allow he operating system to define that. And `httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result;` can cause a deadlock, use `await httpClient.GetAsync(url);` instead. Also `httpClient` needs a `using` to dispose it.

Answer (score -1):

.net 4.8 does not support TLS13.

you can use BouncyCastle or OpenSSL or .NET 5 ...